# How do I handle HR/recruitment being very unresponsive?

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

I applied to a position at a major tech company which I'd love to work for: The technology let alone the brand would be a great advancement in my career.

After contacting me, the HR representative became very unresponsive. If wasn't until my second "So, could we schedule the appointment?" the person replied. We had the first interview and I passed with flying colors, in fact to such a level that they'd schedule a technical interview with an engineer ASAP.

.. Then nothing, again! Once again I've written a follow-up email(thanks for the interview yada yada), no reply. Then, another email "I'm excited for the technical interview, when should we do it?" - once again, no reply.

I'm rather shocked at the seemingly poor communication at what is a major player in the tech industry who apparently are very excited about my profile. I'm interested in working there. But the communication is just weird; If they're that interested, at least spend 20 seconds writing a "guest337, we're super swamped at the moment, we'll get back to you next week. Sorry."

What should I do from here? I have two unanswered emails pending reply. I have interviews lined up with several other companies, but assuming the pay is acceptable, I'd take this one company over another. However, I can't stand being in the dark: If they're dropping me, just say it(but it doesn't appear so).

How do I solve this? Should I straight up say I think the communication is being handled very poorly, and ask what we can do about it?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate: In this case they explicitly stated they were keen to proceed and would schedule an interview ASAP.

Comment: What timeline are you talking about here? No reply for a few days is expected, no reply for a few weeks is not.

Comment: @Dukeling we're talking a week, mind you this is after "we will schedule the interview as soon as possible", over the phone. Radio silence after that.

Answer (score 7):

You've followed up twice now. Continuing to hound them about this will likely hurt you if they're reading the emails (and eventually, they probably will if they haven't already). As will telling them that they're communicating poorly. They may not care - they probably *don't* care because they have so many people like you champing at the bit to work for them. They can afford to annoy a few of the candidates who aren't their top choices.

Don't get emotionally attached to a company, especially if you aren't even working for them. You can't put these "major tech companies" on a pedestal. Just because they look amazing from the outside, it doesn't mean that internally there isn't a huge mess that causes issues like this in recruiting, talent retention, management, career progression, project management, etc.

"Ghosting" people (dropping communication suddenly) is sadly not uncommon for recruiters/HR departments today. Just move on, it's all you can do.

You have other prospects - keep working them. If this company *is* still interested in you but one of your other prospects comes through with a good offer before they respond, it's their loss. You cannot put your job search on hold for a company that acts like this.

Comment: Hounding the HR folks won't help.  Most likely its not intentional, they may be flooded with stuff to do, or they could be incompetent.

Comment: Yes, boot them from the pedestal. I've followed up correctly after an appropriate wait only to receive a "we'll call you" form letter, and then 2 days later a "we need to see you"; but I had wrote to obtain info so I could schedule, their response was *helpful* to **me** (I moved on) but didn't assist them since I replied with a copy of the form letter and let them know they'd been bumped. Needless to say ... - Several months later there was a hostile takeover and the new owners took the patents and closed the place (they were a competitor with 'a better tech'). So lucky me. They were a mess.